# Visibility:hidden propagates slowly to childs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some nested elements with 'effect' class, like this:

```
<style>
   .effect { transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s; }
</style>

<div id=parent class=effect>
   <a href=#>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
   <div id=child class=effect>
      <a href=#>bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
      <div id=childofchild class=effect>
        <a href=#>cccccccccccc</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Normally I would call the following to fade out the parent block including all childs:

```
$('#parent').css({'opacity':0, 'visibility':'hidden'});
```

But I noticed strange behavior (some links are clickable even at the point when everything should be hidden), so I removed the opacity change to demonstrate the problem:

```
$('#parent').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
```

This should skip the opacity change and behave like before - so it should hide the parent (and all childs, as I assume) after only the first second, but it is somehow strange, it demonstrates that it takes several seconds to hide the childs in sequence.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3dbyudy/3/)

It looks like the effect propagate slowly only after it completes to the child elements. How do I hide the element including all childs after the first second, but without the need to temporarily remove the 'effect' class on all the children?

Comment: Remove effect class do the animation, add effect class

Comment: *Why is that? Does the effect propagate slowly only after it completes to the child elements? How do I hide the element including all childs after the first second?"* Those are **two different questions**. If you ask two different questions in the same question, you're likely to get answers that answer one of them or the other, but frequently not both. Questions should be specific: Ask **why** or **how**, but not both.

Comment: "Why" will be buried [somewhere in here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#application).

Comment: OK I've removed the why question and I'm asking how, now :)

Answer (score 2):

It's becuase you have class "effect" also on the children element. So it takes 1s for each element with that class that it is found.

Remove the class from the inner elements and it will work just fine.

If you are not interesting in keeping the empty space of the hidden elements you can use "display:none" as suggested by Nerdkowski

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `effect` class on the last 2 items and it works fine:

```
<div id=parent class=effect>
  <a href=#>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  <div id=child>
  <a href=#>bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
  <div id=childofchild>
    <a href=#>cccccccccccc</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3dbyudy/5/

The cause for the behavior you're describing is that you've got a transition for every child element, so when the script gets to these children it waits for one second before performing the `visibility: hidden`.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to remove the classes you can do it with `hide()` or `fadeOut()` which will also add a nice little effect to the hiding. If you do `hide(1000)` it will also add a subtle effect to the hiding.

Check out updated fiddle (using only `hide()`): http://jsfiddle.net/a3dbyudy/8/

Comment: my question was how to do it without the need to remove the effect class

Answer (score 0):

The transitions work in a cascading manner. So when you apply `visibility: hidden` to the parent element, it takes 1 second for it to finish hiding. At the end, when it is officially `visibility: hidden`, the browser does a style recalculation on the child element, which now inherits the parent's `visibility: hidden`. It takes 1s to apply that new style, and so on down the chain.

This is why it takes 3s for 3 child elements - each one takes 1s to become `visibility: hidden`, and only then does the child element inherit the property and apply its own transition.

---

In addition, your HTML is invalid because it's missing a bunch of quotes -  here's the fixed HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="effect">
   <a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
   <div id="child" class="effect">
      <a href="#">bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
      <div id="childofchild" class="effect">
        <a href="#">cccccccccccc</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I was able to understand what's happening there. So to hide the parent with all its childs, the following code needs to be used to set 'hidden' on all the childs at the same time, so the effect's transition runs simultaneously:

```
$('#parent').find('.effect').addBack().css({'visibility':'hidden'});
```

This adds the hidden css style to all elements with effect class as well as to the parent class (using the addBack()).

Answer (score 0):

Your required:

```
all elements should be hidden in 1 second. But it takes 3 seconds to hide the last!
```

Is there you need :
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/m6j4u00g/)